# Ajuda com Wifi Manager

Tags: android

Eu preciso ler um valor de 2 edittext sendo eles SDDI e Senha e me conectar nesse access point com essas informações

exemplo:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect2);

        cone = (Button) findViewById(conec);
        sddi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        cone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sddi.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && senha.getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Emtre com o Sddi e senha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                    // Check for wifi is disabled
                    if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
                        // If wifi disabled then enable it
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi desativo, ativando-o",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

                        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
                        wc.SSID = String.valueOf(sddi);
                        wc.preSharedKey  = String.valueOf(senha);
                        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
                        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                        int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
                        Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
                        boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
                        Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b);

                    }


                }


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a questão.... Você teve algum problema? Aconteceu alguma exceção? Em que você precisa ajuda?

Comment: já consegui obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
wc.preSharedKey  =  senha.getText().toString();
```

A senhas é um `EditText` e o que você quer é o valor do texto ( `getText` ).

Desta forma : `String.valueOf(senha)` você está pegando a referencia do objeto.

Comment: desculpa a demora fiz como vc falo e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Pode dizer o porque não funcionou? Valeu!

Comment: Consegui, porem eu usei outro código se você quiser eu posso postar aqui